# Why am I unable to load my file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Edited for clarity

From

```
puts $LOAD_PATH
```

I am able to see my load paths. I do

```
$LOAD_PATH << 'C:/rubyfiles'
```

to add ruby files to my search path. I then put some random custom rb file in there and do

```
require 'ya'
```

LoadError - No such file to load

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using so far?

Comment: Why are you putting your own files directly in that directory? That's not the correct practice.

Comment: Then tell me the correct practice. Simply, where do I put my custom rb file and add to search path to require.

Comment: For a single one-off script, for a web project (e.g. Rails, Sinatra, or other) or are you creating utility code that you want available for many scripts?

Comment: Just messing around with the basics in the irb

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
puts "$LOAD_PATH is #{$LOAD_PATH.inspect}"
puts "Files in rubyfiles is #{Dir.entries('C:/rubyfiles').inspect}"
```

and add the output of that debugging to the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to load the file name with `xxx.rb`, you have `load xxx.rb`, not `load xxx`. This is one difference from `require`. Are you clear with that?

Comment: A good point, but given the presence of `require` in the question, this seems unlikely to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your custom .rb files in lib/ folder inside your rails project

**p/s: assuming it's a rails project**

Comment: Oh my mistake, thought this was tagged under rails too

Answer (score 0):

Guess I trusted too much in someone elses code which had an error. Still somewhat new with ruby thus I mistook the loaderror for issues with the main file without bothering to look in the code itself. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this so that the question's treated as answered.